Android studio error am set all sdk api flutter path and everything but the problem is am not solve
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
  > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
     > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

am geeting this error next weeks and am trying to find the solution to solve this but am not find

clear your gradle catche and follow below steps
Step 1: Flutter clean
Step 2: Flutter pub cache repair
Step 3: Invalidate cache and restart(select the clear VCS Log caches and indexes, delete embedded browser engine cache and coockies)
Step 4: Flutter pub get
if above solution not work then follow this github issue
